# Send setState from useState as a props using useCallback

Tags: reactjs

I have the next state in my component;

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

Also inside this component i have another component as a child:

```
<Child setValue={setValue} />
```

How you can notice there i send `setState` as a prop.
Question: How to wrap this `setState` in `useCallback` hook and after that also to pass it as a prop in `<Child/>`? 
 I want to do this to optimize the component  especially to avoid re-renders for Child component.

Comment: Did you mean `setValue={setValue}` ?

Comment: @pmiranda, yes, i changed

Answer (score 2):

assuming setState is a function defined by you

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0):
const setState = useCallback((newValue) =>{
    setValue(newValue)
},[all the dependencies for the function above])

return(
   <Child
      setValue={setState}
   />
)
```

one more thing, **DONT** pass functions inside the dependency array, it will impact the performance negatively

Comment: any source about that statement? My IDE (webstorm) always suggest me to add each dependency, including functions that I will use inside the useEffect.

Comment: I will try to find something, but the reason is that javascript will create a new instance of the function everytime so the useCallback will create a new instance of your memoized function again. But if you want a function to be in the dependency array just wrap that function inside a useCallback too.

Comment: in fact, it is one of the use cases of useCallback, if you want to pass a function as a dependency to useEffect/useCallback (or anything else) you can wrap that function inside a useCallback to prevent extra rerenders.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920
check this out @pmiranda

Comment: OP asked about wrapping state setter function, returned by the `useState` hook, with the `useCallback` hook. React guarantees that the state setter function's identity will always be stable, so you DON'T need to wrap it in the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: Yes, you need not to in that case but initially, it was setValue={setState} in the question there you need to do the wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the props, you have to install the extension [React developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi). You don't need to wrap setState in use callback, because React doesn't change hook setState.

On another note I think you have to pass **setValue**, not **setState**.